# I am trying to search a value and get its key as the output

Tags: python

```
a = {1897:("Diptojit", "Sealdah", 9000000001),
    2224:("Debanjan", "Tarakeshwar", 9000000002),
    1758: ("Avinesh", "Metropolitan", 9000000003),
    2283: ("Biswajit", "Garia", 9000000004)}
n = input("Enter name to know index : ")
lk = list(a.keys())
lv = list(a.values())
#print(lv[0])
for i in range(0,4):

    if n == "('Biswajit', 'Garia', 9000000004)":
        print(lk[lv.index(n)])
    break
```

I am trying to search a value and get its key as the output. This program shows no output while in case of a simple dictionary, when all keys have just one value, this code works perfectly.
Please Help.

Comment: ```"('Biswajit', 'Garia', 9000000004)"``` will have to include the **```()```** as well. Also, the numbers in dictionary are integers and those which ```input``` returns are string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` or `eval()` (former is preferred [[read why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)] though latter is part of the standard library) to convert input to tuple and match objects. Check out the following piece of code:

```
a = {1897:("Diptojit", "Sealdah", 9000000001),
    2224:("Debanjan", "Tarakeshwar", 9000000002),
    1758: ("Avinesh", "Metropolitan", 9000000003),
    2283: ("Biswajit", "Garia", 9000000004)}

try: n = eval(input("Enter name to know index : ")) # converts input string to tuple for matching.
except: print("Invalid input format.")

for idx, details in a.items():
    if n == details:
        print(idx)
        break
```

I have modified your code logic to work for generalized inputs.

Example input: `Enter name to know index : ("Avinesh", "Metropolitan", 9000000003)`

Example output: `1758`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
import ast
...
...

for i,j in a.items():
    if ast.literal_eval(n) == j:
        print(i)
```

`ast.literal_eval` safely evaluates the tuple since it is a string representation of the tuple. Then zip the lists containing keys and values and then check if that is equal to `j`

Comment: It is unnecessary to use `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` separately then zip the values together. Instead, you can just do `dict.items()` which returns an array of key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over every key value pair in the dictionary, and if the value matches the value you are finding, then you return the key. The method `dict.items()` returns us an array of key value pairs, and we can iterate the array to find the value we want.

Eg:

```py
def get_key_from_value(d, search_value): 
    for key, value in d.items(): # (("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3))
        if value == search_value: 
            return key
    return None

d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} 
search_value = 2

key = get_key_from_value(d, search_value) # returns "b"
```

**Edit:**

`dict.items()` returns an array of key value pairs, which we then destructure in the for loop as `key` and `value`. Then, for each iteration we compare it to the value we are searching for, and if it is the correct value, we return the key. If it isn't found, it returns  `None`.

To learn more about python destructuring:  https://blog.teclado.com/destructuring-in-python/

Comment: As the below answers state, if you are comparing with user inputed values, it should be sanitized with ast.literal_eval.

Comment: never use reserved python keywords like "dict" as variable names. Also, this doesn't even answer why OP's code is not working.

Comment: Can you explain how the for loop is working above? I want to know what conditions it is checking.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that dict is a reserved keyword.